# Como verificar se algo foi passado para a pagina php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, switch, case

É até dificil de perguntar pq nao sei se é bem isso, mais vou tentar explicar da melhor forma possivel. Tenho uma pagina onde irei usar o case switch do php para decidir a acao de acordo com o que for passado. Porem preciso que a pagina se apenas for acionada sem passar nenhum parametro ela faca a seguinte verificacao:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM duelos WHERE data > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1440 AND (iddesafiante=$desafiante AND iddesafiado=$desafiado) OR (iddesafiante=$desafiado AND iddesafiado=$desafiante)";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

 //bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
 $statement->bind_param(ii, $iddesafiante, $iddesafiado);

 if($statement->execute()){
print 'Success! Ja duelou com esse oponente nas ultimas 24horas <br />';
 }else{
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}
$statement->close();
```

Dai apos a primeira verificacao tomar as decisoes de acordo se for passado algo

```
 $acao = $_GET (acao);
 switch($acao) {
 case desafiar: {
    QUERY 1
    break;
 }
  case recusar: {
    query 2
    break;
 }

}
}
```

Comment: Jogue esse código no `default` do switch, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: era isso mesmo posta na reposta pra eu marcar como solução

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem duas opções, verifica se existe algo e executa o código desejado ou jogue esse bloco de código no caso padrão(`default`) do switch.

A diferença entre as duas é, a primeira executa ou chama determinado bloco de código **somente** quando `$_GET['acao']` não estiver definido. Já a segunda vai excutar aquele código quando nenhuma das opções anteriores do switch forem satisfeitas ou seja vai entrar no `default` quando `$acao` não tiver nenhum valor ou qualquer outro valor diferente dos especificados no `case` nesse exemplo o `123` cai no `default`.

1 - Opção

```
if(!isset($_GET['acao']){
//executa algo
}

switch($acao){
```

2 - Opção

```
switch($acao) {
    case desafiar: {
        QUERY 1
        break;
     }
    case recusar: {
        query 2
        break;
     }
      default:{
           //esse bloco é executado quando nenhuma das condições for satisfeita
     }

    }
}
```

Comment: esclareceu mais ainda

Comment: Agora outra duvida preciso fazer outra pergunta ou da pra esclarecer por aqui? Pq percebi que a verificacao tera que ser feita em todos os (case), da pra usar isso ainda no swith ou terei que fazer a verificacao em todos case?

Comment: @ArsomNolasco a verificação do isset?

Comment: É porque no tipo esse arquivo ficara sendo atualizando a cada 5 minutos, entao no caso não pode ser default pq os usuarios nao vao ficar pedindo o tempo todo, o defaut no caso sera um echo " propaganda"; no caso mesmo sera executado so dentro do case mesmo case=desafiar 1º executa a verificacao, se caso atender a verificacao passa pra 2º = insert desafio . O mesmo vale para os outros cases sempre havera essa 1ª verificacao. deu pra entender

Comment: @ArsomNolasco é melhor fazer outra pergunta :)